# How to do location forecasting on Chicago Crime Dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, lstm

I am using the dataset https://www.kaggle.com/currie32/crimes-in-chicago and given primary type of the crime I want to forecast the next location of crime. What approach  should I follow ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct questions in the Kaggle page:

> "How has crime changed over the years?"

For this you can simply plot some time based densities and histograms.

> "Is it possible to predict where or when a crime will be committed? Which areas of the city have evolved over this time span?"

No. You might be able to predict aggregates, like monthly crime rates per zip code or something similar, but you will never be able to forecast when the next individual crime is likely to occur: Such an individual event is just too stochastic to be modeled in any reliable way. At best you might be able to fit a poisson process or do some sort of survival analysis, which would give you an average time before a crime is likely to occur, but even that is a stretch.

I would also point out that this is definitely one those situations where just because you can do predictive modeling on a data set doesn't mean you *should* do predictive modeling a data set. The ethical and social risks of false positives and a biased model in this case far outweigh any planning/resource allocation benefits that might be reaped from predicting the crime rates in advance.

Some things are better left "un-modeled".

Comment: You may not be able to forecast precisely where the next crime will occur, but you can certainly calculate probabilistic predictions. And like it or not, there are parts of town where crime *is* more likely. And while I agree that such predictions need to be handled with care, I disagree with a sweeping statement that the risks outweigh the benefits.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I make statement not based on ideology, but based on [real life cases happening here in the US](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/612957/predictive-policing-algorithms-ai-crime-dirty-data/), where profiling and over-policing in certain communities is a major problem. As with all predictive models, ultimately you have to ask: "What is the model being used for?" - if the intent is to prevent crimes before they occur, I don't think that level of accuracy is achievable. -- continued

Comment: -- if the idea is to decrease the likelihood of crimes occurring by increasing police presence as a deterrent, well my previous statement holds: The risk of heavy handed policing far outweigh the benefits.